# Document viewer API in j2ee

Tags: api, jakarta-ee, document, viewer

i am a student and working on my college project. My problem is that i want to open documents like doc, docx, pdf, ppt, txt, xls and some office documents on the browser which are located at my server. it means I dont want to download the document first to see the matter in it. All these document should be opened inside my web browser directly.

I know about google document viewer which provides cloud services for that, but their are some limitations for their use. there are many other cloude services , but they are not fullfilling my need. Is there any api that can help me? By the way my project is in J2EE and server is tomcat, database is Mysql. and my plateform is Windows 7.

If i am able to edit those document from client side , then it will be an extra help to my project.

Comment: you can have a look at http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/viewone-pro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ViewerJS** will solve your problem. It is the easiest way to use presentations, spreadsheets, PDF's and other documents on your website or blog without any external dependencies.

You just need to include the viewer.js plugin inside your project.

1. It is user friendly.
2. You can easily view your documents from server side to the browser.
3. Can support for  .ppt files, .pdf files , .doc files and open office files.

Have a look at here http://viewerjs.org/